# Listing CPU Cores For Multiple CPU Packages

Tags: bash, command-line, cpu

I need to get CPU cores and details per CPU core. I use `cat /proc/cpuinfo` command an it works. But I need to get information for multiple CPU packages. I have only single CPU package. How would the output look like in this situation?

Example CPU setup: 2 CPU packages: CPU package1: Core i7-2000 (4 physical, 8 logical cores), CPU package2: Core i7-3000 (4 physical, 8 logical cores), total 8 physical, 16 logical cores.

Example 1:

```
processor   : 0
.   other info for same core
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2000
.
.   other cores for same CPU package
.
processor   : 7
.   other info for same core
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2000
.
processor   : 8
.   other info for same core
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3000
.
.   other cores for same CPU package
.
processor   : 15
.   other info for same core
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3000
```

or
Example 2:

```
processor   : 0
.   other info for same core
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2000
.
.   other cores for same CPU package
.
processor   : 7
.   other info for same core
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2000
.
processor   : 0
.   other info for same core
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3000
.
.   other cores for same CPU package
.
processor   : 7
.   other info for same core
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3000


OS: Debian-like Linux, Kernel: 4.19
```

Comment: Try dedicated tool for Intel CPUs `i7z`.

Comment: I do not have multiple CPU packages and I need to process the data in the ```/proc/cpuinfo```  or process it by using default system applications.

Answer (score 0):

In setups with multiple physical CPU packages, you won’t see varying model names — all the CPUs have to be matched. In most cases I would expect the enumeration order in `/proc/cpuinfo` to go over physical packages in order, but that can’t be guaranteed; what you need to do is look at the `physical id` in `/proc/cpuinfo` if you want to group the logical cores by physical socket. All the cores from a single socket will have the same physical id, and only those cores.

Comment: Stephen Kitt, about the ```you won’t see varying model names — all the CPUs have to be matched``` information: Is it valid only for PCs in tower chassis form or both for tower PCs with multiple packages and large scale servers (maybe for those have more than a few hundreds-thousands of cores). Note: I am a new Linux (notebook) user, I have migrated from a commercial OS.

Comment: CPUs have to be matched in any tightly-coupled system, regardless of size. Basically, if CPUs are in the same system such that they will show up in the same `/proc/cpuinfo`, they have to match.